# Java Exception not catching, code continues to execute

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

I have a RESTful web-service and i'm having issues catching an exception. I have a parent class that connects to a database using JDBC. The creating of the connection throws the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

Which is fine. I know what causes it and i'll fix it later. The problem is that it is getting caught by the following code:

```
protected Connection connection;

protected void openConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName(dbProperties.getDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbProperties.getConnectionString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught SQLException", e);
        throw new SQLException();
    }
 }
```

By my judgement it clearly catches the exception and throws an SQLException. The child-class however, is not catching it. Code:

```
try {
    openConnection();
    String sql = "...";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught SQLException", e);
    throw new DatabaseException("Database Exception!", e);
}
```

The code continues to the PreparedStatement part, which gives a NullPointer because connection is null.

This causes my service to not return the appropriate database error message, but an unchecked response with the stacktrace in it. Which i absolutely don't want.

What am i doing wrong here? Why is the SQLException not being thrown or caught, causing the DatabaseException to be thrown like it should?

---

The output of the Logging is this:

```
openConnection Caught SQLException
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at dao.AbstractDao.openConnection(AbstractDao.java:22)
    at dao.UserDao.getUser(UserDao.java:16)
    at rest.LoginService.doLogin(LoginService.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:189)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:251)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Where and how is `connection` declared?

Comment: as a protected attribute in the parent class. I added that to the question thank you

Comment: Just for future reference, don't log and then throw again, either handle the exception (even if it's just logging) or don't. And it's probably smart to include the cause of the exception to your new exception.

Comment: @Kars What is the output of `LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Caught SQLException", e);`?

Comment: I edited it in Ernest

Comment: You really should not do `throw new SQLException()`, if you want to re-throw, then rethrow the original exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong with the code that you have shown. Are you sure NullPointerException is thrown exactly where you claim?
Do capture Stacktrace and share.

Comment: Oh you are right. The NullPointer is called in the  closeConnection which is a different exception. I did not differentiate the two. Thank you.